# Ubuntu 14.04 + rbenv + passenger showing public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ubuntu, rbenv

I have a mix of old and new Rails apps (some need Ruby 1.8.7, others 1.9.2, and some Ruby 2.2+) that I want to deploy with Passenger 5, but I'm having trouble getting it to work at all.

I've started with one of my older sites that needs Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.1.0.  When I setup the vhost and try to connect to the application, I just get the index of the public directory.

I have a deploy user that I have set rbenv up for and everything works via Webrick.  I have installed the passenger gem, and ran passenger-install-apache2-module and Apache says the module is loaded.

Here's my vhost file for the application.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName aoi.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/rails/aoi.domain.com/public

PassengerRuby /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p375/bin/ruby

# Relax Apache security settings
<Directory /var/www/rails/aoi.domain.com/public>
  Allow from all
  Options -MultiViews
  # Uncomment this if you're on Apache > 2.4:
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have tried running Apache both as the www-data user and deploy user, I have tried chowning the directory to both www-data:www-data and deploy:deploy, and I have added the www-data user to the deploy group so that the user should be able to use the deploy user's rbenv ruby, but all of this has been met with failure.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

**Updated vhost config**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName aoi.domain.com

PassengerRoot /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/passenger
RailsBaseURI /
PassengerAppType Rack
<Location />
  PassengerBaseURI /
  PassengerAppRoot /var/www/rails/aoi.domain.com
</Location>


# Relax Apache security settings
<Directory /var/www/rails/aoi.domain.com/public>
  PassengerEnabled On
  PassengerRuby /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p375/bin/ruby

  Allow from all
  Options -MultiViews
  # Uncomment this if you're on Apache > 2.4:
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Passenger 5 will expect a rackup file.  So you'll need a `config.ru` file.  Does the rails 2 site have one?

Comment: No, the Rails 2 app does not have a rackup file.  I can make one though.

Comment: Can you update the site to a later version of rails 2?  When I put some rails 2 apps on passenger 5 with nginx I bumped them to `2.3.18` and they work.  `rake rails:update` is your friend :)

Comment: That would a a fair amount of changes for me to make on 13 separate applications. I wasn't hoping to have to do something so drastic :)

Comment: I've been trying to update one application as a test.  rake rails:update shows no warnings, I've changed the rails version in environment.rb, and moved the application controller from application.rb to application_controller.rb, but I'm greated with this fine error.

`/var/www/rails/aoi.domain.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in 'load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Inflector (NameError)`

Comment: I'd put it on bundler http://bundler.io/v1.3/rails23.html It'll be easier to manage dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to set

```
PassengerRoot #add the path to your passenger binaries
RailsBaseURI /
PassengerAppType Rack
<Location />
    PassengerBaseURI /
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/rails/aoi.domain.com
</Location>
<Directory /var/www/rails/aoi.domain.com/public>
    PassengerEnabled On
    # and add your other settings
</Directory>
```

notice it's not pointed to the public but the app root directory.
Then put the following lines to your aoi.domain.com/config.ru -create it if it's not there.

```
require "config/environment"

use Rails::Rack::LogTailer
use Rails::Rack::Static
run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I just add the top portion to my vhost config file, and added the config.ru to my app, but I'm still presented with just a directory listing after restarting Apache.  Any other ideas?

Comment: how do you want to access your app, could you tell me the url you want to access it through?

Comment: I have a DNS record created for it.  I want to access it via http://aoi.domain.com (this is a placeholder for the real domain).  Obviously, right now it isn't working publicly.

Comment: I revised above to show my current config.  Unfortunately, Apache no longer starts.